# show fixed button only when parent div is in view

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

i have a div with some images.
first, only one row is shown, when i click "more" all the images are shown.

to close the div i have to scroll to the bottom of the div to close the container
when there are many images, the distance to the bottom is too far

so i want an extra button for closing which has a fixed position
but the button should be shown only if the div is in the viewport -  when i scroll down to the next image container, the less button of the above container should disappear

my markup looks like this

```
<article id="1">
    <h1>Titel</h1>
    <a class="weniger" href="#">less</a>

    <ul class="thumbs">
        <li>img</li>
        <li>img</li>
        <li>img</li>
        <li>img</li>
        <li>img</li>
        <li>img</li>
        <li>img</li>
        <li>img</li>
        <li>img</li>
    </ul>
    <a class="more" href="#">mehr</a>

</article>
```

the jquery code looks like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".more, .weniger").on("click touch",function(){

        var wid = jQuery(this).parent().attr("id");

            jQuery("#"+wid+" .weniger").show();
            jQuery("#"+wid+" .thumbs").css("height","auto");
            jQuery("#"+wid+" .thumbs").css("overflow","auto");

            jQuery(this).text("less");


        return false;
    });
});
```

the css

```
.thumbs{
    height: 182px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.thumbs li{
    float: left;   
    height: 182px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.thumbs img{
    height: 100%;        
}

article{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.weniger{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 100px;
    right: 20px;
    float: right;
}
```

i have made a jsfiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/oliverspies/VZFtj/6/

Comment: comparing `$('.thumbs').offset().top`, `document.body.scrollTop` and `document.height` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$().offset().top`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) returns the element position relative to the document.

[`$().outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) returns the element size including padding and border.

[`$(window).height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) returns the viewport size.

[`$().scrollTop`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) returns the element scrollbar position

the [`$(window).scroll(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event is triggered whenever  the window is scrolled.

Try:

```
$(function(){
  $('article').each(function(){
    var $el = $('.thumbs',this);
    var $w = $(window);
    var $less = $('.weniger', this);
    var $more = $('.more', this);
    $(window).on("scroll resize",function(){
      if( $w.scrollTop() > $el.offset().top + $el.outerHeight()
          || $w.scrollTop() + $w.height() < $el.offset().top
      ){
        $less.hide();
      }else if($more.text()=="more"){
        $less.show();
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: all in all it works great! the only thing is, if i scroll down and the button disappears and then scroll up again, the button does not appear again

Comment: i think i have it; else if($more.text()=="less") instead of ""; thanks for your help - this works like a charm

Comment: note that storing a button state in its view (here, in its text) is a bad idea. What if you decide to translate the application later?